# Does the Iron Fist perk affect melee weapons?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm aware of the Big Leagues perk, but can the Iron Fist perk affect a melee weapon such as brass knuckles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [Steam post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/492379439686510258/) that states it boosts unarmed weapons such as the Deathclaw Gauntlet and Knuckles.

> Iron Fist is for unarmed weapons, which exist and include the Knuckles, Power Fist, and Deathclaw Gauntlet.

[The Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_weapons#Fist_weapons)  for fist weapons states:

> Fist weapons benefit from the Iron Fist Perk as well as from Strength. Note that fist weapons cannot be used while wearing power armor.

Knuckles are on the list from the Wiki, so they do benefit from the perk.

To be clear, the weapons that benefit from the Iron Fist perk are:

- Knuckles
- Power Fist
- Deathclaw Gauntlet
- Boxing gloves
- Meat Hook
- Butchers Hook

Comment: Another annoyingly worded perk description in Fallout strikes again!

Comment: If you are going for stealth, the x10 ninja sneak attack do NOT work for unarmed weapons.  You end up with only a x4.5 bonus.